# How to reimplement the SessionVariable/WebSession variable concept of Invoke-RestMethod in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, session-variables, invoke-restmethod

I want to wrap several `Invoke-RestMethod` calls by two functions and I have to pass the `WebSession` variable between them. Goal:

```bsh
Login -SessionVariable MySession
# do some work while using $MySession
Logout -WebSession $MySession
```

The `Login` and `Logout` functions will probably look like that:

```bsh
function Login {

    Param(
        [String]SessionVariable
    )
    Invoke-RestMethod ... -SessionVariable $SessionVariable
    Invoke-RestMethod ... -WebSession ???
    Invoke-RestMethod ... -WebSession ???
}

function Logout {

    Param(
        WebSession
    )
    Invoke-RestMethod ... -WebSession $WebSession
}
```

But how can I use the name of the session variable in `Login` to pass it to the `-WebSession` parameter? Is it even possible to reimplement this SessionVariable/WebSession concept of `Invoke-RestMethod`? I think it has something to do with a `call-by-reference` by `[ref]`, but how do I build the bridge between a variable name (a string) and an actual variable?

Answer (score 0):

Specify a global scope modifier in the string value for your session variable, for example:

```
Login -SessionVariable "global:MySession"
```

See this link for more details on [PowerShell Scope Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#scope-modifiers)